# 3.3 The read character string cannot be output in reverse order in C

Tags: c

I want to write the strings read from the file data01.in to data03.out in reverse order.However, when I run it, both files have the same contents. What should I do? After that, open the file in which the output result you created is written and the model file to check if it matches, compare it character by character from the beginning, and check if the contents of the two files match. I want to find out what it is and create a program that displays the results, so please tell me how to create that program.

source

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
    
    
        #define MAX 1000
         
        int main ()
        {
          char in_filename [] = "data01.in";
          
          char out_filename [] = "data03.out"
    ;
          FILE * fpin, * fpout;
         
          char buf [MAX];
          int c;
          int n;
          int i;
         
          / * Open the input file. * /
          if ((fpin = fopen (in_filename, "r")) == NULL)
          {
            printf ("Failed to open:% s \ n", in_filename);
            exit (1);
          }
         
          / * Open the output file. * /
          if ((fpout = fopen (out_filename, "w")) == NULL)
          {
            printf ("Failed to open:% s \ n", out_filename);
            fclose (fpin);
            exit (2);
          }
         
         
          / * Read data up to the maximum number of buffers * /
          for (n = 0; n <MAX; ++ n)
          {
            if ((c = fgetc (fpin)) == EOF)
              break;
         
            buf [n] = (char) c; / * Don't forget to cast to char. * /
          }
         
          / * If EOF is not reached even after the maximum number of buffers is reached, an error is processed as buffer overflow.
          * /
          if (n == MAX)
          {
            printf ("Buffer overflow! \ N");
            exit (3);
          }
         
          / * Output the contents of the buffer. * /
          for (i = 0; i <n; ++ i)
          { 
            fputc (buf [i], fpout);
          }
         
          / * Don't forget to close each opened I / O file. * /
          fclose (fpout);
          fclose (fpin);
         
          return 0;
        }
```

data01.in

```
    A Turing machine is a mathematical model of computation that defines an abstract machine,[1] which manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules.[2]
    Despite the model's simplicity, given any computer algorithm, a Turing machine capable of simulating that algorithm's logic can be constructed.[3]
    "Turing machine" from Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine). (Access date: 2020/10/01)
```

data03.out

```
    )10/01/0202 :etad sseccA( .)enihcam_gniruT/ikiw/gro.aidepikiw.ne//:sptth(aidepikiW morf "enihcam gniruT"
    ]3[.detcurtsnoc eb nac cigol s'mhtirogla taht gnitalumis fo elbapac enihcam gniruT a ,mhtirogla retupmoc yna nevig ,yticilpmis s'ledom eht etipseD
    ]2[.selur fo elbat a ot gnidrocca epat fo pirts a no slobmys setalupinam hcihw ]1[,enihcam tcartsba na senifed taht noitatupmoc fo ledom lacitamehtam a si enihcam gniruT A
```

Comment: `for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; -- i)` when writting

Comment: In fact, tell me what line I should put it in.

Comment: Or, read the input file backward

Comment: The line you are writting the file

Comment: What is "3.3" in the title supposed to mean? To avoid confusion you should not add things that are completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: OH, thanks Cid!! It can work! All I have to do now is write a program to check if the two files match. Please tell me that too.

Comment: You have added an extra **nested** loop to your code, which makes the code broken and the question completely bogus. I have reverted your edit. If you want to answer your own question, please use the answer button. Do not edit answers into questions.